# Question mark next to "via [APP NAME]" Facebook iOS Feed Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

When I display a feed dialog to the user, I'm running into a small issue where there's a question mark displayed next to the "via [APP NAME]" portion of the dialog.

[image: Question mark]

I'm not sure if that's an error on my end, or if that's just how Facebook displays dialogs. My code for displaying this is as follows:

```
- (bool) PostToWallWithDialog:(NSString*)a_pMessage
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [self GetParams];

    // Invoke the dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
             NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             } else {
                 // Handle the publish feed callback
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self ParseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Share button
                     NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                      @"Posted story, id: %@",
                                      [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                     NSLog(@"%@", msg);
                     // Show the result in an alert
                     [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                                 message:msg
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil]
                      show];
                 }
             }
         }
     }];

    return true;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*) GetParams
{
    // TODO: Externalize these strings
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 @"App Name", @"name",
                 @"Caption goes here!", @"caption",
                 @"Description goes here!", @"description",
                 @"http://example.org", @"link",
                 @"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png", @"picture",
                 nil];
}
```

Any way to get that image to go away?

Comment: Do you have the 16x16 icon setting populated in your application settings?

Comment: @JimRubenstein That must be it! I didn't catch it in the documentation. Can you put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you populate the 16x16 image in your application settings